# Spacetime length vs inner product in the definition of the Lorentz groups $O(1,3)$

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, group-theory, definition

I learned that the full Lorentz group $O(1,3)$ is the set of transformations that preserve the spacetime length $$\textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{x}=x_0^2-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2$$
where the vector $\textbf{x}=(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

It was then said that $O(1,3)$ preserves the dot product
$$\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{y}=x_0y_0-x_1y_1-x_2y_2-x_3y_3$$
where the vectors  $\textbf{x}=(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $\textbf{y}=(y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3)$.

Why is this true?

Comment: Hi @TaeNyFan. I removed the determinant bit to try to make it more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) $$x\cdot y= \frac{(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2}{4}.$$