# Homomorphism between $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ and $\mathrm{O}(1, 3)$

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, group-theory, representation-theory

By definition if $L$ is an element of the Lorentz group we have $(x,y)=(Lx,Ly)$.
Now $S$ be an element of $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$. Usually people defines the homomorphism
$\lambda:\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C}) \longrightarrow \mathrm{O}(1, 3)$ by
$$\lambda(S)x=SA_xS^\dagger$$

Where
$$
A_x:=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
x_0+x_3 & x_1-ix_2 \\
x_1+ix_2 & x_0-x_3
\end{array}\right).  
$$
The proof that $\lambda(S)x \in \mathrm{O}(3, 1)$ is by defining the inner product by $$(\lambda(S)x,\lambda(S)x)=\det[\lambda(S)x] \tag 1$$
We can show that $\det[\lambda(S)x]=(x,x)$.

I am not understanding  why  $\lambda(S)$ is an element of the Lorentz group. Shouldn't we prove that $$(\lambda(S)x,\lambda(S)y)=(x,y)~?$$
How to define  $(\lambda(S)x,\lambda(S)y)$?

Comment: It's really the double covering of Spin(1,3) of SO(1,3) and the isomorphism of SL(2,C) with Spin(1,3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. OP particular question boils down to the use of the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/610978/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. More generally for the group homomorphism, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 0):

First there is a bijection between Minkowski space, $M$ and Hermetian 2x2 matrices, $Hm[2]$, this is given by $X: M \rightarrow Hm[2]$ where $x=(x^\mu) \rightarrow x^\mu.\sigma_\mu$.

We then see that $det[X(x)] = |x|^2$, where the latter is the square of the Minkowski norm.

Next, we define an action of $SL(2,C)$ on $Hm[2]$ by $S.A:=SAS^\dagger$ where $S \in SL(2,C)$ and $A \in Hm[2]$. This action preserves the determinant, that is $det(S.A)=det(A)$.

Then putting the two together, we see that $det[S.X(x)] = det[X(x)] = |x|^2$. Hence the action acts by orientation preserving isometries on Minkowski space, and so we get a group map $\alpha: SL(2,C) \rightarrow SO^+(1,3)$. It turns out that this maps is surjective with kernel $\{Id, -Id\}$, and so is a double cover.